# App Rejected - Crash Log

Tags: ios, swift, ipv6

Can anyone explain to me what does this crash log mean?

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   puvoice2                        0x000000010026014c 0x1000fc000 + 1458508
1   puvoice2                        0x000000010025b7b8 0x1000fc000 + 1439672
2   UIKit                           0x0000000197f1d6a4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
3   UIKit                           0x000000019812da98 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3524
4   UIKit                           0x0000000198133808 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1656
5   UIKit                           0x0000000198148104 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3139 + 48
6   UIKit                           0x00000001981307ec -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
7   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000193bd392c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
8   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000193bd3798 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
9   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000193bd3b40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191faab5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191faa4a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191fa80a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191ed62b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
14  UIKit                           0x0000000197f167b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 608
15  UIKit                           0x0000000197f11534 UIApplicationMain + 208
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Apple will send some information why your app crash please share this information

Comment: Apple Rejection Reason:

We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Next Steps

Please revise your app and test it on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to ensure it will launch without crashing.

Noting man that we did all our tests and could not find any crash, the app works fine. I do not know what causes the crash.

Comment: This is the 4th build that Apple reject for the same reason. I tried to symbolicate the crash log but I got the text that I already post it in my original question.

Comment: You ar using Reachability class and  afnetworking   or not

Comment: We are using NetworkReachabilityManager from Alamofire and we are not using AFNetworking

Comment: Did you tried to replicate that crash on IPV6 network? There must be something wrong which you didn't found in your testing before release.

Comment: We do not have an IPV6 Network in our location, that's why I could not find any crash, I tried to create an IPV6 Network using sharing internet on my MacBook but it doesn't work, I could not find any crashes.

Comment: Did you checked a mark this "Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated app crash logs" while creating a build.?

Comment: Make Sure, you are not using IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses.

Comment: @anilkukdeja I don't know I will recheck this.

Comment: @V12 Yes I already read the Apple IPV6 Network documentation and we don't have any hard-coded IP addresses.

Comment: pls also ensure the server support the IPV6 (http://ready.chair6.net/). but i think maybe its not related to IPV6, did you run app on AdHoc (Release mode) and check. its seems like any UI type issue.

Comment: @V12 The server support the IPV6, I already check this link.
I ran the app in Release mode, no crashes.

Comment: @user2731717 Have you got any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Change** in NetworkReachabilityManager

```
  var address = sockaddr_in()
  address.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
  address.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
```

**to** 
//For IPv6 it will work

```
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in6()
zeroAddress.sin6_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
zeroAddress.sin6_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6)
```

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: When I changed the below code, the instance of the NetworkReachabilityManager returned nil